# Why is a qualified name required after the second level of inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, qualified-name

I ran into a problem, that I somehow managed to solve, but still would like to understand the language and the reasoning behind it. I have the following system of three classes:

#### File `class_a.hpp`

```cpp
#pragma once

class A
{
public:
    A();
};
```

#### File `class_b.hpp`

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "class_a.hpp"

class B : A
{
public:
    B() : A() {}

    virtual double do_something(A &with_object) const;
};
```

#### File `class_c.hpp`

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "class_b.hpp"

class C : B
{
public:
    C() : B() {}

    double do_something(::A &with_object) const; // but differently than class B
};
```

Now if I was *not* to use the fully qualified name for the type `A` in the C's `do_something()` method, I'd get the following error still in editor:

> type "A::A" (declared at line 27 of "class_a.hpp") is inaccessible C/C++(265)

What could be possible causing any ambiguity in this case? I certainly haven't redefined or used the name `A` as an identifier. Is there something happening in the background that makes use of the class name?

Also is the override of the `do_something()` method guaranteed to work this way, or is qualifying the type `A` in the B's method also required?

Any advice and/or pointers are also greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just checking: are you deliberately or accidentally using private inheritance?

Comment: private inheritance still shouldn't make this happen. Is your compiler recent enough?

Comment: @TanveerBadar - No, it should make that happen.

Comment: @Passerby To be honest, I didn't know there's different types of inheritance. So yes, I did it on accident...

Comment: Also my apologies for making a duplicate... I tried searching both on the web and here on SO, but it's hard to formulate the question that would get you the answer, when you don't understand what's going wrong.

Comment: No worries. A duplicate can actually be a good thing, believe it or not. Since you formulated your question differently, it now serves as a sign post for folks who may come across the problem in the future and ask it the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among other things that are inherited, there are [*injected-class-names*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name). You can think of them as of hidden type aliases: `class A` has something like `using A = A;` in it, pointing to itself.

And remember that class inheritance is `private` by default.

Since `B` inherits from `A` privately, `C` can't access the contents of `A`, which includes `A`'s injected-class-name.

> Also is the override of the `do_something()` method guaranteed to work this way, or is qualifying the type `A` in the `B`'s method also required?

Yes, the override in `B` is valid. Since `B` inherits from `A` *directly*, it can access all its contents, regardless of whether the inheritance is private or not.

---

Your code is similar to following. I replaced the injected-class-name with an actual type alias, and got the same behavior.

```
class A
{
  public:
    using A_type = A;
};

class B : A
{
  public:
    virtual double do_something(A_type &with_object) const;
};

class C : B
{
  public:
    double do_something(A_type &with_object) const;
};
```